# CSS shape-outside from image's url doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a shape-outside, so far I fail, how handle this situation ?
I have made the image:

- transparent background in PNG's extension,
- floating on the left.

It seems theses are the sole requirement for this move according to my readings.

I have stocked the image on Google drive, Im wondering if Google drive makes the image opaque when restituting to me.

```css
.page{
    display:flex; 
}

.img{
  float: left;
  height:550px;
  margin:50px 0 0 50px;
  shape-outside: url(https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1GIboZJR9L7lXyvvwBrxGDrR9N9SjntE4);
}
```

```html
<div class="page" >
<img 
     class="img"
     src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1GIboZJR9L7lXyvvwBrxGDrR9N9SjntE4"/>
   <p>One November night in the year 1782, so the story runs, two brothers sat over their winter fire in the little French town of Annonay, watching the grey smoke-wreaths from the hearth curl up the wide chimney. Their names were Stephen and Joseph Montgolfier, they were papermakers by trade, and were noted as possessing thoughtful minds and a deep interest in all scientific knowledge and new discovery. Before that night—a memorable night, as it was to prove—hundreds of millions of people had watched the rising smoke-wreaths of their fires without drawing any special inspiration from the fact.</p>
</div>
```

Any hint would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your error console:

> Access to image at
>   'https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1GIboZJR9L7lXyvvwBrxGDrR9N9SjntE4' from
>   origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

You can not load an image from that resource. Also note `shape-outside` is [not supported by microsoft browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: thanks for your answer, Im trying that in local in firefox recent 67.0.1 and it still fails, so I assume that the problem is elsewhere

Comment: The issue is google drive. You can not serve an image from there, as per the error message, which was from Chrome. The warning about Microsoft browsers is incedental.

Comment: Check your error console! Jon P is absolutely right. well, you might probably want to load the image from a local dir like so to avoid this error:  shape-outside: url('img/circle.png');

Comment: I have ckecked my console that why I assumed the problem was Google drive. efectively it works locally :).